# ¿Cómo incluir una función PHP en una cadena string?

Tags: php, string, funciones

Necesito incluir funciones PHP en una cadena String y no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo.
El código es este:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$direccion= $_POST['direccion'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$html = "
         <div class='cliente'>
               $nombre
            <br>
               <?php 
                  if(isset($telefono)){
                     echo $telefono;
               } ?>
            <br>
              <?php 
                  if(isset($direccion)){
                     echo $direccion;
               } ?>
            <br>
              <?php 
                  if(isset($email)){
                     echo $email;
               } ?>
         </div>
         ";
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo para que lo reconozca como php y no como parte del string?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor manera de hacer lo que pretendes es evaluando con `isset()` primeramente si lo que le llega por `$_POST` existe y de ser así se le aplica el valor que llega. Al inicializar las variables como cadena vacía en caso de que no llegue por `$_POST` no se te a a imprimir en la cadena **HTML**.

**PHP**

```
$nombre = '';
$telefono = '';
$direccion= '';
$email = '';

if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}

if(isset($_POST['telefono'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['telefono'];
}

if(isset($_POST['direccion'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['direccion'];
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST['email'];
}

$html = "
         <div class='cliente'>
               $nombre
            <br>
                $telefono;
            <br>
                $direccion;
            <br>
                $email;
         </div>
         ";
```

Comment: Es decir, hacer todas las funciones antes del string y en el string solo poner la variable definitiva. En el caso de que una esté vacía simplemente la ignora, ¿es así? Voy a intentarlo y te digo en un rato. ¡Gracias!

Comment: El `string` solamente debería contener código que el cliente (el navegador) interprete, no es operativo enviar al cliente código que se tiene que ejecutar en el servidor (PHP el navegador no sabe que hacer con ello). Y no es que en caso de estar vacía se ignora, se va a imprimir igualmente si tiene contenido como si no, pero al tener una cadena vacía lo que se imprima no tiene consecuencias (es como hacer un `echo ""`.

Comment: Me funciona phpMyGuel. Había probado muchas cosas pero justo esto no se me había ocurrido ¡muchas gracias!

Comment: Para eso estamos, lo que no se le ocurre a uno se le ocurre a otro. ¡Un placer!